# how to make every input into bold in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text "red" and a textfield I need to input red in my textfield if it is equals to red it will change the background color of the text into red.. but while typing i need to make each letter into bold  type if the corresponding input is equal to the text "red" for

example: i type "r" so it will make the  r in red in bold and then type "re" it will make re in red bold if i type ref it will only bold the "re" i have only done the red background color

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var str = $("#color").html();
        var r = str.substring(0, 1);
        var e = str.substring(1, 2);
        var d = str.substring(2, 3);

        $('#theInput').keyup(function() {
            var v = $(this).val();
            if (v == str) {
                $("#color").css("background-color", "red");
            } else {
                $("#color").css("background-color", "white");
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: You will have to design a custom text input widget to achieve this, because several different color styles cannot be applied at the same time to the text of an `<input>` element.

Comment: Then, what is the use variable r,e,d???

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i only limit it in word red.. other colors is not necessary

Comment: @JqueryKing r,e,d variables has a value of r,e,d also

Comment: @Cyran, I may have misunderstood, but *if i type ref it will only bold the "re"* implies that two styles are applied: a bold red one for "re" and the "standard" (normal black) one for "f". That is not possible with plain `<input>` elements.

Comment: it will only affect the text "red" not the input or the textfield.

you will compare only the textfield input to the textor label that is "red" <-- this one should be bold in re but not in d if input is ref

Comment: @Cyran, so you want to apply the styles to another element? Even then, there can only be one color style per element, so you will probably have to create several `<span>` elements to apply the different styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create `span` elements for each letter, and target those to make them bold (*preferably with a css class*).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var color = $("#color"),
      str = color.text(),
      letters = color.children();


  $('#theInput').keyup(function() {

    var v = $(this).val();

    if (v == str) {
      $("#color").css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      $("#color").css("background-color", "white");
    }

    letters.removeClass('correct');

    // check each letter of the input and bold the ones in the color that match
    for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (v[i] == str[i]) {
        letters.eq(i).addClass('correct');
      }
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.correct {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="color"><span>r</span><span>e</span><span>d</span></div>
<input type="text" id="theInput" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var str = $("#color").text();
            console.log(str);
            
            var r = str.substring(0, 1);
            var e = str.substring(1, 2);
            var d = str.substring(2, 3);
            console.log(str.indexOf("red"));
            $('#theInput').keyup(function() {
                var v = $(this).val();
                var newhtml = "";
                if ( v.indexOf(r) >= 0) {
                    newhtml += '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">r</span>';
                } else {
                    newhtml += '<span>r</span>';
                }

                if ( v.indexOf(e) >= 0) {
                    newhtml += '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">e</span>';
                } else {
                    newhtml += '<span>e</span>';
                }

                if ( v.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
                    newhtml += '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">d</span>';
                } else {
                    newhtml += '<span>d</span>';
                }

                $("#color").html(newhtml);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color">red</div>
<input id="theInput">
```